# tsql - joining two tables from different databases hosted on separate servers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have got 2 databases sitting on different physical servers and linked. I need to join DB1.T1 with DB2.T2 and create an id. The problem is performance. My senior insists using a function and I have created it below.

```
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getXXXId', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.getTRId;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getTRId (@gcPRef bigint)
RETURNS varchar (100)
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER --may not be necessary. not sure.
AS
BEGIN

     DECLARE @TRID varchar (100);
     SELECT @TRID =  CONVERT(varchar (12), hu2.PropId) 
              + '_'+ CONVERT(varchar (12), c.WSId)
        FROM [172.29.110.133].DB1.dbo.checks c
        join [172.29.110.133].DB1.[dbo].VHier
                          ON VHier.xx= c.xx
        join [172.29.110.133].DB1.[dbo].rvc
                          ON rvc.xx= VHier.xx
                          AND rvc.yy= VHier.yy
        join [172.29.110.133].DB1.[dbo].HUNIT hu
                          ON c.xx= hu.xx
    WHERE c.CheckId = @gcPRef;

     RETURN (@TRID);
END;
GO
```

I use the query below to query each checkid using the function above.

```
select getTRId(guestCheckPRef), guestCheckid from DB2.Guest_CHECKS GC
where GC.closeBusinessDate = '2014-06-25'
```

A couple of things you may like to know:

- DB1 and DB2 are hosted on different physical servers.
- I am not a DBA so please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.
- Approximately 45000 records created daily. so this is the amount of rows..
- I have already tried joining them without involving a function. it takes forever. in 30 seconds, 450 records returned only. I cannot keep tables locked for a long time.
- CONSTRAINT [DB1.PK_CHECK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
- CONSTRAINT [DB2.XPKGUEST_CHECKS] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
- I do not know if constraints are playing a role here. DB2.GUEST_CHECKS.guestCheckPRef is NOT even a FK here. guestCheckPRef  is PK in DB1.CHECK.
- performance is very poor. I need to return ***DB2.propid + DB2.wsid + DB1.guestCheckid.***

This is all I can give for now. Any suggestion is appreciated. It does not have to be done with a function.

Thanks in advance. Regards.Oz.

Comment: Have you tried to have this function in DB1 itself? Because your function don't use any DB2 tables. Just have that function in the local db & call it from the other db.

Comment: Linked servers will almost **always** destroy your performance. Regardless of how well-tuned the rest of your query is, the linked server will kill you. Also, why are you doing this as a function and not a stored procedure?

Comment: @NMK. thank you. maybe I did not state it clearly. this function is stored on DB2, accessing DB1 remotely. yes i have stored the function on DB1 and attempted to access it remotely from DB2 unsuccessfully as the sources say that you cannot call a function remotely. Besides our client will use this and they only have access to DB2.Regards.Oz.

Comment: @alroc. you are very right about linked servers. I have got a local db has 10 thousands data and it takes only few seconds to retrieve the same amount of data with this method. It is a well-structured db. But this request is very unusual came from a client. So I am just desperately looking for a solution. I have already developed it in different ways but could not satisfy them.BTW, I did not see any performance difference between SPs and functions.I will give it a try just to have an idea. Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things to try or consider:

1. Have you checked that the query is using the best available indexes? You could try running the query through the query analyser to see if there's any indexes you could add to improve performance.
2. What version of SQL Server are you running? Depending on the version you might be able to replicate the table from one server to the other to alleviate the cost of running a query across your network.
3. I notice that several of the joins are across to the other server - could you consolidate all of those joins into a single view that is optimised using indexes - may result in less network traffic.
4. Try putting your function on the other server and calling it from the first server to see if there's any performance improvement.

Comment: I think #4 here is going to be the best option without replicating data between the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a "select" in a function is generally considered "not a good idea". The select in the function will be repeated once *for each row in the result set*, which is probably why the performance is bad.

Erp. This was supposed to be a comment, not an answer. To turn this into a proper answer, rewrite the query as a join, without using the function. (I.e. take the contents of the function and integrate it into a single join.)

Your example query should look something like this:

```
;with getTRID as 
(SELECT CONVERT(varchar (12), hu2.PropId) 
  + '_'+ CONVERT(varchar (12), c.WSId) AS TRID
  FROM [172.29.110.133].DB1.dbo.checks c
join [172.29.110.133].DB1.[dbo].VHier
  ON VHier.xx= c.xx
join [172.29.110.133].DB1.[dbo].rvc
  ON rvc.xx= VHier.xx
  AND rvc.yy= VHier.yy
join [172.29.110.133].DB1.[dbo].HUNIT hu
  ON c.xx= hu.xx)
select getTRId.TRID, guestCheckid from DB2.Guest_CHECKS GC
inner join getTRID ON CheckId = guestCheckPRef
where GC.closeBusinessDate = '2014-06-25'
```

N.B. I'm working from memory here so, please, no flames for syntax errors! Thx.

Steve G.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and time. I have tried this and fixed the syntax was not a big deal. It is resource intense as well. takes so much time even to return 100 records. I believe this is a network/linked server issue.

Comment: Another suggestion, if Time truly is paramount, is to cache the data in question on the 'local'server from all the remote servers before doing any joins. I would implement this as first select relevant data to a temp table on each server, then copy the temp data table across the network. This should give you the least impact to the source tables and also help reduce the impact of network latency.